# Get search word Hits ( number of occurences) per document in Lucene

Tags: search, lucene

Can any one suggest me the best way to get Hits( no of occurrences ) of a word per document in Lucene?..

Answer (score 6):

Lucene uses a field-based, rather than document-based, index.
In order to get term counts per document:

1. Iterate over documents using [IndexReader.document()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexReader.html#document%28int%29) and isDeleted().
2. In document d, iterate over fields using [Document.getFields()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/document/Document.html#getFields%28%29).
3. For each field f, get terms using [getTermFreqVector()](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/all/org/apache/lucene/store/instantiated/InstantiatedIndexReader.html#getTermFreqVector%28int,%20java.lang.String%29).
4. Go over the term vector and sum frequencies per terms.
5. The sum of term frequencies per field will give you the document's term frequency vector.

Comment: +1. You may have to consider the stemming and other transformations that the text has undergone. For example, if you searched for the word "beauty" on a stemmed field, the actual term from the index would be "beauti."

Answer (score 1):

[SpanTermQuery.getSpans](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_0/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanTermQuery.html#getSpans(org.apache.lucene.index.IndexReader)) will give an enumeration of docs and where the terms appears.  The docs are sorted, so you can just count the number of times each doc appears, ignoring the position info.