# custom synonyms support for lucene

Tags: lucene, synonym

can any one direct me on creating the **custom synonyms** using lucene in java?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use Solr, you can use a [SynonymFilterFactory](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/AnalyzersTokenizersTokenFilters#solr.SynonymFilterFactory). Otherwise, Lucene In Action has an example of how to write a synonym filter if you want to do it in pure Lucene.

Comment: How do I convert the synonyms.dat file into lucene index for synonyms? The synonym.dat is simple text file having customs synonyms in it. All synonyms are comma separated and next set is followed in next line.

Comment: @sharma: the format of the synonyms text file is given in the page I linked.

Comment: Xodarap - Will I be able to find the number of hits in a document using lucene?

Comment: @sharma: yes, see [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1920726/get-search-word-hits-number-of-occurences-per-document-in-lucene). If you have additional questions, please ask them separately rather than as comments.